# How to fix this ' Property 'list' does not exist on type 'AngularFireDatabaseModule'.ts(233 '

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am trying to a push a data to a firebase database but the property 'list' does not exist on type 'AngularFireDatabaseModule'

Typescript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {  NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-chat',
  templateUrl: 'chat.html',
})
export class ChatPage {
  username: string=''
  message: string=''

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    public db: AngularFireDatabaseModule
    ) {
      this.username = this.navParams.get('username')
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.db.list('/chats').push({
     username: this.username,
     message: this.message
    })

    console.log(this.navParams);
  }

}
```

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313801/whats-the-difference-between-angularfiredatabasemodule-and-angularfiredatabase

Answer (score 0):

Something is already wrong when you are *injecting a module* in your component like this `constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabaseModule)`

External modules are imported into your module in the "imports" array of your @NgModule, E.g. `@NgModule({ imports: [SomeExternalModule]})` .

Services are injected into your component in the constructor e.g. `constructor(private myService: MyService)`.

Taken from https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/ionic/cli.md#adding-the-firebase-database-and-auth-modules:

> For example if you application was using both Firebase authentication and the Firebase database you would add:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { firebaseConfig } from '../environment';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [ MyApp ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig), // imports firebase/app needed for everything
    AngularFireDatabaseModule, // imports firebase/database, only needed for database features
    AngularFireAuthModule, // imports firebase/auth, only needed for auth features
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
})
```

Taken from https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/ionic/cli.md#7-inject-angularfiredatabase:

> Open /src/pages/home/home.ts, and start to import AngularFireDatabase and FirebaseListObservable:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(
    public db: AngularFireDatabase,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
  ) {}

}
```